# ScrollView with fixed height

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I've created a ScrollView, and I have a fix height of 1000. I also have two really long labels in it, and set the constraints of top, leading and trailing both of the labels. But here comes the problem. My font size is 18.0, which is perfectly fit on iPhone 4 and 5, but I have like 100 points of empty space below the last label on iPhone 6 and plus.

I don't know how should I fix this, maybe with different fonts or just set a required height, but I don't know how to do it. I'm also not sure if my constraints are right. I don't want to work with textViews, because I want to have a few images too.

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: *I don't want to work with textViews*. Use attributed strings and text attachments.

Comment: I also want my images to clickable

Comment: Actually, do you know what is that problem, when I have a textView in a ViewController, and when I run my app, the textView shows up in the middle, so I have to scroll up. I don't know if u understand it

Comment: *I also want my images to clickable* and? *the textView shows up in the middle*. that was discussed many times. consider using the search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This demo may help you,

[image]

- First set these constraints on scrollview [let,right,top,bottom]
- Second set these constraints to scrollview subview ie. container view [left,right,top,bottom,height constraint[1000],horizotal in container];
- Now check it work on iphone6 and iphone 6 plus without empty space or not
- Then add yours views in container view.

Hopefully this will help you to fix your problem

Thanks

Comment: yea I did the exact same thing, I've already created that scrollView, and I still have an empty space below the last label :(

Comment: Have u added constraint like for label 1 add [top,left,right] & label 2 add [bottom, left ,right], add a vertical space between label1 to label2.